# Is there any update on the new designs?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, design

I'm just wondering when this site will get the new modernised design, along with the new profile page.

Answer (score 3):

See: [List of communities with base css updates completed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253359/list-of-communities-with-base-css-updates-completed).

Skeptics is on the list of sites yet to be updated, with no indication of where in the sequence we'll fall. They may be considering a more extensive update of our design, so our update might take longer.

Also, see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/06/stack-exchange-podcast-65-the-word-has-two-meanings-you-see/. Each re-design takes a long time.

Answer (score 1):

### StackExchange sites left: 10

- Stack Apps
- Photography
- Wordpress Development
- Role-playing Games
- Electrical Engineering
- Physics
- Science Fiction and Fantasy
- ***Skeptics***
- Mi Yodeya
- Christianity

### Probability for Skeptics' turn to be next: 1/10